# Event delegation on click of an option, doesn't work on cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, event-delegation

My previous question (that was closed) -> [Jquery - Cloning a div which includes input unordered lists. How to get the dropdown to work in the cloned row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959801/jquery-cloning-a-div-which-includes-input-unordered-lists-how-to-get-the-drop)

I was referred to this answer: -> [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

I'm stuck at which static ancestor to use as with each one i try, the cloned version will not register any clicks.

For example, in my first version, I used the .on as so.. clicking an option from the dropdown to run a function that will assign a class selected, which will unhide the next dropdown.

```
$(".option").on("click", unhideoption2);
```

but with each parent/static selector I add in, it still doesn't register any clicks on the cloned versions

e.g

```
$(".optionlist").on("click", ".option", unhideoption2);
```

or

```
$(".cselect").on("click", ".option", unhideoption2);
```

or

```
$(".row1").on("click", ".option", unhideoption2);
```

Should I be adding the event delegation to the row that is being cloned instead of to the individual inputs? Although when I try that also, it still doesn't register the clicks on the cloned row.

```
$(".rows").on("click",'.clonerow', clonerow);
```

Where am I going wrong with the event delegation?

https://jsfiddle.net/pfhnr9uk/4/

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
<div class="row1">
  <div class="cselect options1">
    <input type="text" disabled placeholder="Select n1">
    <ul class="optionlist">
      <li class="option option1">Business</li>
      <li class="option option2">Hair</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="cselect options2 hide">
    <input type="text" disabled placeholder="new test">
    <ul class="optionlist">
      <li class="option option1">test</li>
      <li class="option option2">option 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row2">

  <div class="cselect options3">
    <input type="text" disabled placeholder="Select n2">
    <ul class="optionlist">
      <li class="option">Something</li>
      <li class="option">Else</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clonerow">
click me
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* ugly reset */

.cselect {
  position: relative;
}

.cselect input {
  background: #fff;
}

.cselect ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.cselect li {
  padding: 10px 5%;
  list-style: none;
}

.cselect li:hover {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.2);
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() { // DOM ready


  $(".cselect").each(function() {

    var $input = $(this).find("input");
    var $dropDown = $(this).find("ul");

    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $dropDown.stop().slideToggle();
    });

    $dropDown.on("click", "li", function() {
      $input.val($(this).text());
    });

  });

});

var newnewid = 0;
var $cloneplayerclause = jQuery(".row1").clone(true);

function clonerow(){
  
  newnewid++;
  var $sectionClone = $cloneplayerclause.attr("id", newnewid).clone(true);
  $('.rows').append($sectionClone);
  
  
}

function unhideoption2(){
 $(".option").removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
 if($('.option1').hasClass('selected')){
 $('.options2').removeClass('hide');
 }
 }

$(".option").on("click", unhideoption2);
$(".clonerow").on("click", clonerow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events handlers are not cloned, but what you can do is create event handler on the `.rows` box like so:

```js
$(function() { // DOM ready
  const rows = $(".rows").on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
      const input = rows.find(e.target);
      input.parent().find("ul").stop().slideToggle();
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains("option")) {
      const li = e.target;
      const ul = li.parentNode;
      const divSelect = ul.parentNode;
      const row = divSelect.parentNode;
      const input = divSelect.querySelector("input");
      if (!divSelect.dataset.hidden)
        row.dataset.hidden = li.dataset.hidden;

      input.value = li.textContent;
      $(input).click();
      for(let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++)
      {
        ul.children[i].classList.toggle("selected", ul.children[i] === li);
      }
      const hiddenRows = row.querySelectorAll(".cselect[data-hidden]");
      for(let i = 0; i < hiddenRows.length; i++)
      {
        hiddenRows[i].classList.toggle("hide", !row.dataset.hidden || row.dataset.hidden != hiddenRows[i].dataset.hidden);
      }
    }
  });
});
var newnewid = 0;
var $cloneplayerclause = jQuery(".row1").clone(true);

function clonerow() {

  newnewid++;
  var $sectionClone = $cloneplayerclause.attr("id", newnewid).clone(true);
  $('.rows').append($sectionClone);


}

$(".clonerow").on("click", clonerow);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ugly reset */

.cselect {
  position: relative;
}

.cselect input {
  background: #fff;
}

.cselect ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.cselect li {
  padding: 10px 5%;
  list-style: none;
}

.cselect li:hover {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.2);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="cselect options1">
      <input type="text" disabled placeholder="Select n1">
      <ul>
        <li class="option option1" data-hidden="1">Business</li>
        <li class="option option2">Hair</li>
        <li class="option option3" data-hidden="3">Face</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cselect options2 hide" data-hidden="1">
      <input type="text" disabled placeholder="new test">
      <ul>
        <li class="option option1">test</li>
        <li class="option option2">option 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cselect options2 hide" data-hidden="3">
      <input type="text" disabled placeholder="face type">
      <ul>
        <li class="option option1">type 1</li>
        <li class="option option2">type 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">

    <div class="cselect options3">
      <input type="text" disabled placeholder="Select n2">
      <ul>
        <li class="option">Something</li>
        <li class="option">Else</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clonerow">
    click me
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Vanowm thank you for replying! I have made a js fiddle out of the answer, but it seems to not let you select an option. It clones correctly, but I can't click on 'Business' for example. Here is the jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/un2p8ox3/

Comment: fixed hidden row

Comment: Hi Vanown, I will give you accepted answer. Just one further question.. In my original code, a 2nd dropdown appears when the 1st option 'Business' is selected. It seems this doesn't work in yours, I see you took out the function i used for it. Do you know what is causing that to not work? I want the 2nd dropdown to only appear after the first option is selected on dropdown 1 - the issue i was facing with this, was the cloned version didn't respond to the 1st option being selected, so the 2nd dropdown never appeared on the cloned row. thanks

Comment: It's working in my version...unless I don't understand how it supposed to work...once "business" is selected in first dropdown it unhides the hidden field. Same thing happens in the cloned row

Comment: I created this up to date jsfiddle, it works in the original row but in the cloned version it doesn't unhide the hidden field -> https://jsfiddle.net/un2p8ox3/1/

Comment: in my version hidden row has an additional class "hidden" and unhideoption2 function was merged into main event function.

Comment: Hi yes, I get you now i missed that html part from my jsfiddle, sorry. I appreciate the help

Comment: If I was to add more dropdowns, would I need to do an if statement on the div.classList.contains and then compare each class name? const hasHidden = div.classList.contains("options1") && div.parentNode.querySelector(".hidden");

Comment: Current implementation will only work with one hidden dropdown. If you want have multiple hidden dropdown that would be shown depending on which option selected it would need additional modification.

Comment: updated the code (both html and js changed) It will now allow add multiple hidden fields and which hidden field belong to which option is controlled via 'data-hidden' attribute

Comment: Would this work if the 3rd appeared depending on the 2nd dropdown not the 1st?  i.e. could you show the 3rd dropdown depending on the 2nd dropdown option?

Comment: Do you mean show more than one hidden dropdown in one row? - not with this method.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example of how to do it.

The key is here:

```
function clonerow(){

        let cloneplayerclause = $(".row1").clone(false);

      let sectionClone = $(cloneplayerclause).attr("class", "rowx").find(".cselect").each(function() {

        var $input = $(this).find("input");
        var $dropDown = $(this).find("ul");

        $(this).on("click", function() {
          $dropDown.stop().slideToggle();
        });

        $dropDown.on("click", "li", function() {
          $input.val($(this).text());
        });

      });
      
      $('.rows').append(sectionClone);
      
      
    }
```

Complete example, try sample:

```js
$(function(){


  $(".cselect").each(function(){

    var $input = $(this).find("input");
    var $dropDown = $(this).find("ul");

    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $dropDown.stop().slideToggle();
    });

    $dropDown.on("click", "li", function() {
      $input.val($(this).text());
    });

  });
  
  let cloneplayerclause = $(".row1").clone(false);
  
  window.cloneplayerclause = cloneplayerclause;

});


function clonerow(){

    let sectionClone = $("<div class='rowx' />")
    
    $(cloneplayerclause).clone(true, true).find(".cselect").each(function(){

    var $input = $(this).find("input");
    var $dropDown = $(this).find("ul");

    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $dropDown.stop().slideToggle();
    });

    $dropDown.on("click", "li", function() {
      $input.val($(this).text());
    });
    
    $(sectionClone).append(this);

  });
  
  $('.rows').append(sectionClone);
  
  $(".option").on("click", unhideoption2);
  
}

function unhideoption2(){
 $(".option").removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
 if($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.options1 ul li').hasClass("selected")){
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.options2').removeClass('hide');
 }
 }

$(".option").on("click", unhideoption2);
$(".clonerow").on("click", clonerow);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* ugly reset */

.cselect {
  position: relative;
}

.cselect input {
  background: #fff;
}

.cselect ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.cselect li {
  padding: 10px 5%;
  list-style: none;
}

.cselect li:hover {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.2);
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

    <head>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="rows">
        <div class="row1">
          <div class="cselect options1">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="Select n1">
            <ul>
              <li class="option option1">Business</li>
              <li class="option option2">Hair</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <div class="cselect options2 hide">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="new test">
            <ul>
              <li class="option option1">test</li>
              <li class="option option2">option 2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">

          <div class="cselect options3">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="Select n2">
            <ul>
              <li class="option">Something</li>
              <li class="option">Else</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clonerow">
        click me
        </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I make the option part more dynamic in the function unhideoption2

```
if($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.options1 ul li').hasClass("selected")){
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.options2').removeClass('hide');
 }
```

Comment: thank you that works! Is there any way to have the cloned version appear like the original? By that I mean, the 2nd dropdown is only shown when the first option in dropdown 1 is selected, but if i select an option and the 2nd dropdown appears and then clone, the cloned version has the 2nd dropdown too when it should be hidden. Is this due to 'let cloneplayerclause = $(".row1").clone(false);' happening inside the function and after the click instead of being cloned beforehand? Thanks for the help

Comment: The function called unhideoption2 has the key here, i was about 30 mins debugging, understand it now.

Comment: What would I need to change in that function?

Comment: You need to change the selector because if you for example click in Hair option, you don't will unhide the element, i edit my post with this change on unhideoption2, the change is this -> ``if($('.option1, .option2').hasClass('selected')){``

Comment: I beat the last part making the options more dynamic ```if($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.options1 ul li').hasClass("selected")){
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.options2').removeClass('hide');
 }```